# Using Jenkins Job-DSL Configure block for webhook trigger

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

Please help to understand what are doing wrong with my DSL

```
job('example') {
configure { triggers ->
           triggers << 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.gwt.GenericTrigger' {
              token("exampleTocken")
              causeString("Generic Cause")
          }
        }
}
```

It's executing without errors, but option of webhooks is not implementing.

I have did same action manually in Jenkins and found next xml of job :

```
<triggers>
   <org.jenkinsci.plugins.gwt.GenericTrigger plugin="generic-webhook-trigger@1.47">
     <spec></spec>
     <regexpFilterText></regexpFilterText>
     <regexpFilterExpression></regexpFilterExpression>
     <printPostContent>false</printPostContent>
     <printContributedVariables>false</printContributedVariables>
     <causeString>Generic Cause</causeString>
     <token>exampleTocken</token>
     <silentResponse>false</silentResponse>
   </org.jenkinsci.plugins.gwt.GenericTrigger>
 </triggers>
```

Why my builder is not working?

Answer (score 0):

the configure injection should be at the following location, and spec() must be included.  without the spec() option, the webhook trigger will not be enabled in the job.

```
job('example') {
  configure {
    it / triggers << 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.gwt.GenericTrigger' {
      spec()
      token("exampleTocken")
      causeString("Generic Cause")
    }
  }
}
```